# cakephp/app/webroot/ not found when installing cakephp on Apache servor

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

**What I'm trying to do:**

I've developed a web application with cakephp 2.2.1 on wamp. Now I want to install it on an Apache server (version 2.2.16).

**Error**:

> The requested URL /inetpub/wwwroot/cakephp/app/webroot was not found
>   on this server.

**What I did:**

That's seemed to me to be a .htaccess error.

I checked that

> LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so

was uncommented.

I made sure that

> Options FollowSymLinks
>       AllowOverride All

was enabled for the wwwroot/cakephp dir. Then I checked that all the .htaccess files were conform to the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html#apache-and-mod-rewrite-and-htaccess).

Still no luck.

**Question:**

Does anyone know what's going on?

**EDIT:** here is app/webroot/index.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Index
 *
 * The Front Controller for handling every request
 *
 * PHP 5
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright 2005-2012, Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright 2005-2012, Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @package       app.webroot
 * @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9
 * @license       MIT License (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
 */
/**
 * Use the DS to separate the directories in other defines
 */
if (!defined('DS')) {
    define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
}
/**
 * These defines should only be edited if you have cake installed in
 * a directory layout other than the way it is distributed.
 * When using custom settings be sure to use the DS and do not add a trailing DS.
 */

/**
 * The full path to the directory which holds "app", WITHOUT a trailing DS.
 *
 */
if (!defined('ROOT')) {
    define('ROOT', dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
}
/**
 * The actual directory name for the "app".
 *
 */
if (!defined('APP_DIR')) {
    define('APP_DIR', basename(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
}

/**
 * The absolute path to the "cake" directory, WITHOUT a trailing DS.
 *
 * Un-comment this line to specify a fixed path to CakePHP.
 * This should point at the directory containing `Cake`.
 *
 * For ease of development CakePHP uses PHP's include_path.  If you
 * cannot modify your include_path set this value.
 *
 * Leaving this constant undefined will result in it being defined in Cake/bootstrap.php
 */
//define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', ROOT . DS . 'lib');

/**
 * Editing below this line should NOT be necessary.
 * Change at your own risk.
 *
 */
if (!defined('WEBROOT_DIR')) {
    define('WEBROOT_DIR', basename(dirname(__FILE__)));
}
if (!defined('WWW_ROOT')) {
    define('WWW_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . DS);
}

if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
    if (function_exists('ini_set')) {
        ini_set('include_path', ROOT . DS . 'lib' . PATH_SEPARATOR . ini_get('include_path'));
    }
    if (!include ('Cake' . DS . 'bootstrap.php')) {
        $failed = true;
    }
} else {
    if (!include (CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH . DS . 'Cake' . DS . 'bootstrap.php')) {
        $failed = true;
    }
}
if (!empty($failed)) {
    trigger_error("CakePHP core could not be found.  Check the value of CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH in APP/webroot/index.php.  It should point to the directory containing your " . DS . "cake core directory and your " . DS . "vendors root directory.", E_USER_ERROR);
}

App::uses('Dispatcher', 'Routing');

$Dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
$Dispatcher->dispatch(new CakeRequest(), new CakeResponse(array('charset' => Configure::read('App.encoding'))));
```

Comment: did you bake the app? Sometimes the path to `webroot` gets hard coded in `app/webroot/index.php`, and if you're copying it from a `wampp` installation the paths may be wrong.

Comment: I did bake the app. But it is not the source of the error as it also appear with a clean install of cakephp. I will still add the content of the file in my question.

Comment: Does your apache have `mod_rewrite` installed? Does your apache have read/execute rights on those folders?

Comment: mod_rewrite is installed, it transforms  /inetpub/wwwroot/cakephp in  /inetpub/wwwroot/cakephp/app/webroot

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem solved:

First if your website is

> http://www.example.info/tmp/

put respectively in the three .htaccess:

```
RewriteBase /tmp/ 
RewriteBase /tmp/app/ 
RewriteBase /tmp/app/webroot
```

and replace

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

by

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last RewriteBase be: /tmp/app/webroot ?

Comment: @DinkarThakur Did it worked? I'm going to edit my answer anyway.

Comment: Which .htaccess file are you referring to?